# Implementation of Least Mean Squares algorithm

Tags: least-squares

I am attempting to do a 'recreational' exercise to implement the Least Mean Squares on a linear model. My goal is to compare it to the the OLS estimates for $\beta$ so that I can verify I am performing calculations correctly.

Here is the general algorithm I am using:

I start with an estimate for $\beta = [1,1]'$. I choose the number of iterations, say $n=100$, to be reevaluated if the fit doesn't converge. Finally, I choose $a=0.5$ (not sure what I 'good' value for a is, but this is my initial guess.

Now, for $i=1:n$, I calculate $\hat{y}=X\bullet\beta$, and use this value to update my $\beta$ guess:
$$\beta_{i+1} =\beta_{i}-a\bullet (\hat{y}-y)X$$

However, using this algorithm, my $\beta$ estimates explode very quickly. I have done a search online for some helpful materials, but most of them have applications in signal processing, which overly complicates the algorithm, making it difficult to apply here. Can anyone assist in pointing out my error, suggesting a source with a simple application, or is able to provide pseudo code for the problem?

Comment: For further context: I am using the bike share data set from the  Center for Machine Learning and Intelligent Systems: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bike+Sharing+Dataset and I am considering temperature as the independent variable and total bike rentals as the dependent variable. I realize that there is curvature in the data and that this isn't a particularly good representation of the data, but I am simply attempting to illustrate the algorithm and am not concerned with the full model just yet.

Comment: You do not seem to use squared error anywhere, aren't you?

Comment: Tim, I don't use it in my algorithm but I do observe it as the simulation runs. Does anyone know if I need to include the column of ones in the matrix to solve for the intercept in this algorithm? I assume yes, but I'm still getting a strange result...

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm looks correct.

Without looking at your implementation all I can offer are a few resources to help you along.

[Andrew Ng's Lecture on this subject (PDF)](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf)

[Some random bloggers implementation in R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/linear-regression-by-gradient-descent/)

I'd rather comment by don't have the rep yet.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Your sources helped me fix some minor issues and I was able to find my error. I think the problem was just an extremely poor initial guess for beta. I used the OLS estimates for beta and chose initial values near(ish) to those, then the algorithm was successful!